# GetFileAttributes on (locked) system file

Tags: winapi

Calling `GetFileAttributes` for a file such as C:/pagefile.sys returns `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`, and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. Yet it should definitely be possible to retrieve information about system files - e.g. being able to tell if it is a file or a directory. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You should be able to use `FindFirstFile` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using `FindFirstFile` you can get information of `pagefile.sys` file. You can get the file's other information from [`ffd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;    
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile( "C:\\pagefile.sys", &ffd );

if ( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind )
{
    return 0;
}

if ( !( ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ) )
{
    _int64 filesize = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
    filesize <<= 32;
    filesize |= ffd.nFileSizeLow;
    printf( "%s is %I64u bytes", ffd.cFileName, filesize );
}

FindClose( hFind );
```